# Is it possible to add Junit5 extensions programmatically to a @TestTemplate test using @RegisterExtension?

Tags: junit, junit5

Using Junit version `5.9.2` I am trying to programmatically add parameter resolvers extension for a test class constructor with a `@TestTemplate` annotation.
I am trying to add the extensions programmatically using `@RegisterExtension`.

Example:

```java
public class MyTestClass {

  @RegisterExtension
  static final TestDependencyResolver resolverExt = new TestDependencyResolver(/*...*/);
  
  private final TestDependency dependency;

  public MyTestClass(TestDependency dependency) {
    this.dependency = dependency;
  }

  @TestTemplate
  @ExtendWith(SomeContextProvider.class)
  void test() {
    //...
  }
}
```

I have tried:

1. making `resolverExt` field non `static`
2. Movine `@ExtendWith(SomeContextProvider.class)` to class level

And other possible combinations of 1 and 2.

In all cases the ctor parameter `dependency` is not injected and `TestDependencyResolver::resolveParameter` is not called, which to my understanding means the object was created without/before registering `TestDependencyResolver`, please correct me if I am wrong.

Is what I am trying to achieve possible? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was not Junit5 but `TestTemplateInvocationContextProvider` I was using.

I used `PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider` which seems to have a bug and throws `NullPointerException` when resolving Ctor params, I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-jvm/issues/1666) for it if you want more details.